# Tuning samples in Kontakt 5

Tags: sampling, kontakt

So I have some machine samples I am trying to tune to pitch, the piece is in the C3 range and I am wondering if there is a better way than ~I am attempting. At the moment I am using Kontakt to slice the audio then strapping an instance of Span to the insert and figuring out the pitch of each sample. I am then manually tuning each to the pitch which is quite time consuming. Is there another way?

Thanks

Rory

Answer (score 2):

what i do if i need quick tune my sounds, i add standart kontakt piano, route it to the same midi channel play the note and tune my samples by ear, to match the piano pitch.

btw...celemony melodyne can help you a lot in this situation, try the demo.

Comment: sounds like there is no automated way, so its basically get on with it :)

Comment: I do the same! - b

Answer (score 0):

KeyMapPro by Redmatica has pitch analysis and tuning for Kontakt, but isn't available any more as apple bought it and discontinued it...